# C# What is the best way to split one large class to multiple, so variables would be shared between them

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I am trying to find a way to use a group of classes that will share methods and variables.

I want to make a class or classes that will work with data, in the format similar to csv file.
I created a large class named "Data", it is supposed to hold main variables with, well, data.

However, from what I am learning online, it's best that one class deals with just one aspect of program.

So, the Data class will have actual variables, like the text, columns and the like, and a usual constructor.

```
internal class Data
{
    private readonly int _id;
    protected DateTime LastUpdateTime;
    protected readonly List<Column> Columns = new List<Column>();
    protected List<string> DataText = new List<string>();
    protected string Headers;

    public Data()
    {
        _id = Global.Last();
        LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Data(List<string> dataText, char separator, Boolean hasHeaders) : base()
    {
        DataText = dataText;
        //DataManageColumns dataManageColumns = new DataManageColumns();
        new DataManageColumns().CreateColumns();
        new DataManageSeparator().Separator = separator;

        if (hasHeaders == true)
        {
            new DataManageHeaders().SetHeaders();
            new DataManageHeaders().ExcludeHeadersFromDataText();
        }
    }

    public int GetId()
    {
        return _id;
    }
}
```

But, I do want to make every aspect of work, like getting an actual text, or counting the number of columns, or saving the time when there was a last change, or whatever be in its own class.

Example:

```
class DataManageColumns : Data
{
    public void CreateColumns()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DataText.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] splitLine = DataText[i].Split(Global.CurrentData().DataManageSeparator.Separator);

            if (i == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < splitLine.Length; j++)
                {
                    Columns.Add(new Column(j, splitLine[j]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Column> GetColumns()
    {
        return Columns;
    }

    public void SetColumns(List<Column> newColumns)
    {
        foreach (Column column in newColumns)
            column.SetSerial(column.GetSerial());
    }
}
```

It is inherited from the Data class, so it can use its variables.

**But! How I can access DataManageColumns methods from the base Data class, or from any other class?**
I did try adding it to Data like that:

```
internal DataManageColumns DataManageColumns = new DataManageColumns();
```

My original thought was to use something like:
specificData.dataManageColumns.DoWhatever();

While it didn't show an error, it crashed on running with **Stack Overflow Exception**.

**I quickly understood why and will post it here to help others: new Data creates new ManageColumns, which calls for a new Data that again creates another ManageColumns and so infinitely.**

The question is, how to solve this?

What I tried:

I tried using Nested classes, by the nested class can't use vars from main class (unless there is a way I don't know).

I considered making a partial class: but this will still be using one class for many aspects, which is against SOLID principles.

I tried making sub-classes static, but using static makes it impossible to inherit or be inherited.

I believe I am not the first who wants to do something like that, and it isn't supposed to be that hard to implement. But I can't find a way to do it.

Can you please help?

Thank you,
Evgenie

**UPD: I highly prefer, if it's possible, to access methods from sub-classes from using Data.**

Like if using data object of Data class:

```
data.MethodFromSubClass();
```

Comment: If the thing you're working with doesn't do the thing you want to do with it, then you need to consider if you're trying to do the wrong thing with it. You're asking how to do something (separate classes) while at the same time retaining the thing that inherently defeats its purpose (no logical separation or encapsulation). The most likely explanation here is a basic misunderstanding of OOP principles. That's not something an answer here can fully address, it may be better to instead resort to a tutorial/online resource/mentor to explain the basic purpose of OOP and encapsulation.

Comment: To maybe express it a bit more clearly: you expect to be able to freely access methods from anywhere, which suggests to me that you're thinking in static terms (i.e. global scope). OOP by intention does _not_ use a global scope, instead forcing you to encapsulate your logic and working with specific instances within specific contexts. This is conceptually and fundamentally orthogonal to what you're expecting your code to do. The better solution here is to revisit the OOP basics and learn how to use OOP in the way it is intended to be used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Auburg also explained what I am doing wrong, and I think I now understand my mistake in the very approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But! How I can access DataManageColumns methods from the base Data
> class, or from any other class?

**You don't**. Prefer composition to inheritance ([Composition v Inheritance)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#:%7E:text=To%20favor%20composition%20over%20inheritance,gives%20the%20design%20higher%20flexibility.&text=Initial%20design%20is%20simplified%20by,business%2Ddomain%20classes%20via%20inheritance.), since a DataManageColumns class isn't a specific type of Data class (in the way a triangle is a type of shape). The former makes use of the latter and furthermore the `Data` class shouldn't need to know anything about `DataManageColumns` or any other class that makes use of it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I know now how to write the code correctly. I will mark this as answer.